# im developing a php chrome extension but it only shows the code in the extension

Tags: php, google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension, download

I'm developing a PHP chrome extension but it only shows the code in the extension.
like this.

popup.php (already edited it in the manifest.json file):

an HTML file with an include of the downloadmp3.php. (when I put it on the StackOverflow site between code tag it doesn't show..)

I have a function in my downloadmp3.php file but it doesn't work. (when I open the popup.php in the browser it works but not in the extension)

downloadmp3.php:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $url = (isset($_POST['url']) && !empty($_POST['url'])) ? $_POST['url'] : false;
    if (!$url) {
        echo "Vul alstublieft een url in";

    } else {
        $source = file_get_contents($url);
        $source = urldecode($source);

        // Verkrijg de video titel.
        $vTitle_results_1 = explode('<title>', $source);
        $vTitle_results_2 = explode('</title>', $vTitle_results_1[1]);

        $title = trim(str_replace(' – YouTube', ”, trim($vTitle_results_2[0])));

        // Extract video download URL.
        $dURL_results_1 = explode('url_encoded_fmt_stream_map', "url=", $source);
        $dURL_results_2 = explode('\u0026quality', $dURL_results_1[1]);

        // Force download van d  video.
        $file = str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($title)).'.mp3';

        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
        header("Content-Type: video/mp3");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        readfile($dURL_results_2[0]);

        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please read the chrome docs. Nowhere does it say that a server-side language like php is supported (thanks god it isnt, doesnt make sense to)